# OpenXML not creating document on production, but fine in Dev

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api2

I have launched a new application at work. We create letters using OpenXML which works flawlessly on Dev, but on production the solution is not returning.

```
$("#createLetter").on("click", CreateLetter);

function CreateLetter() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Letters/CreateLetter",
    data: { 
      EntityType: "@overview.EntityType", 
      EntityId: @overview.EntityId, 
      Recipient: $("#Recipient").val(), 
      TemplatesLocation: $("#templatePath").val(), 
      SaveAs: $("#saveAs").val() 
    },
    async: false,
    success: openLetter
  });
}

function openLetter(data) {
    openFile(data);
    window.location.reload(false);

}
```

Controller Method:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateLetter(CreateLetter input)
{
  Recipient obj = logic.SplitRecipientInput(input.Recipient);

  input.RecipientId = obj.RecipientId;
  input.RecipientType = obj.Type;
  input.Username = Helpers.GetLoggedInUser();

  var x = logic.CreateLetter(input);
  if (x.Success == 1)
  {
    return Json(x.Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json("Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Consumption Logic:

```
public CreatedLetter CreateLetter(CreateLetter input)
{
  CreatedLetter response = new CreatedLetter();
  Parameters.Add("TemplatePath", GetApiValue(input.TemplatesLocation));
  Parameters.Add("EntityType", GetApiValue(input.EntityType));
  Parameters.Add("EntityId", GetApiValue(input.EntityId));
  Parameters.Add("RecipientId", GetApiValue(input.RecipientId));
  Parameters.Add("RecipientType", GetApiValue(input.RecipientType));
  Parameters.Add("Username", GetApiValue(input.Username));
  Parameters.Add("SaveAs", GetApiValue(input.SaveAs));
  response = Api.WebRequest<CreatedLetter>("CreateLetters", Parameters, Method.POST) as CreatedLetter;
  return response;
}
```

API Controller method:

```
[ActionName("CreateLetter")]
[HttpPost]
public ApiResponse CreateLetter(LetterCreateInput input)
{
  try
  {
    LetterTemplateLogic logic = new LetterTemplateLogic();

    Random r = new Random();
    var randomId = r.Next(100000, 999999);

    string fileName = string.Format("{0} - {1}", randomId, input.SaveAs);
    input.SaveAs = fileName;

    // Get all objects for Letter
    List<object> objs = logic.TemplateObjectsRetriever(input.EntityId, input.EntityType, input.Username, randomId);

    objs.Add(logic.GetRecipient(input.RecipientId, input.RecipientType));

    // Get save location
    string saveLocation = logic.LetterLocationResolver(input.EntityId, input.EntityType);

    var data = logic.OpenAndUpdateTemplate(objs, input.TemplatePath, input.SaveAs, saveLocation, FileExtension);

    AttachmentInput letterAttachment = new AttachmentInput();
    letterAttachment.Id = input.EntityId;
    letterAttachment.FileTypeId = 1;
    letterAttachment.Path = data;
    letterAttachment.Username = input.Username;
    letterAttachment.Description = fileName;
    letterAttachment.EntityType = input.EntityType;
    logic.InsertLetterAttachment(letterAttachment);
    return ApiResponse.Return(data);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return ApiResponse.Error(ex);
  }
}
```

This returns literally nothing on production. No errors in the console, no errors from the API which logs erroneous calls. I was hoping someone could make a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't diagnose the issue right now, however I can tell you that your primary concern should be to remove `async: false`

Comment: Thanks - I have done, tried with and without. Sorry this was at the expense of hours of yanking my hair out!